# Matlab: How to find a point in a bounding box

Tags: matlab, find, bounding-box

I have an array of points or locations that are scattered throughout a big matrix, and I have a small bounding box inside the matrix. I need a way to check if the points in the array are within the bounding box. Thanks for your suggestions.

```
BoundingBox = [BB1,BB2,BB3,BB4];
Array = [x1,y1;x2,y2;x3,y3;x4,y4;x5,y5;x6,y6];
```

I have tried

```
ismember([BB1,BB2,BB3,BB4],Array);
```

and

```
ismember(rectangle('Position',[BB1,BB2,BB3,BB4]),Array);
```

but nothing is working

Comment: I was hoping for a ismember answer but I can't figure out how to configure the bounding box

Comment: I don't understand. Question says "have a bouncing box", where is the configuration issue?

Comment: ismember(rectangle('Position',[BB1,BB1,BB3,BB4]),Array) or ismember([BB1,BB1,BB3,BB4],Array) are only returning 0's weather the points in Array are in the bounding box or not

Comment: ismember has nothing to do with your question, at least as far as i understand it. What is `[BB1,BB1,BB3,BB4]`? What is Array?

Comment: ismember is a way to tell if a point from one array or matrix is a member of another array of matrix. I thought it would work but have been unsuccessful so far

Comment: How to you describe a cubolid with 4 parameters? Is this a 2d-Problem? I assumed 3d because of the term "bounding box"

Comment: A bounding box is a (bwconncomp / regionprops) property. BB1 and BB2 are the x,y cooridinates of the bounding box first corner, BB3 and BB4 are the height and width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read [`ismember()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)'s documentation more carefully:

> > Array elements that are members of set array

So, this check is related to set operations.

Instead, you should use [`inpolygon()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) to check whether points are inside a polygon.

Comment: This looks like its what I need but how do you enter the coordinates of the polygon?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
% Array         an Nx2 matrix containing the X,Y coordinates of the points with
%               respect to the big matrix
%
% BoundingBox   a vector of length 4 representing the bounding box as follows:
%               [minimumX, minimumY, sizeX, sizeY]


isInBox = @(M,B) (M(:,1)>B(1)).*(M(:,1)<B(1)+B(3)).*(M(:,2)>B(2)).*(M(:,2)<B(2)+B(4));
isInBox(Array,BoundingBox);
```

If you change the strict inequalities to `>=` and `<=` you will also accept points on the bounding box.

Comment: This is a good idea, but I think the equation is wrong. I think that B(1)+B(3) and B(2)+B(4) should be replaced with B(3) and B(4), respectively.

Comment: Fixed the equation accordingly. If I am somehow mistaken, please reject my edit!

Comment: @robguinness  Thanks, but the original equation was correct, just poorly documented.  The OP stated (in a comment) that the bounding box was of the form `(xmin,ymin,width,height)`.  Your update assumes that the coordinates are given as `(xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax). I have rolled back the equation, but held on to your code comments.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense now! I should have read through those comments before criticizing your answer! In any case, I hope the answer is more usable, given that the format of the objects are included.

Comment: For others: I only have one upvote to give to this answer, but in my opinion, it's much better than the accepted answer. Inpolygon is a "black box" for most users and a bit overkill for this particular problem.