# How to vectorize a pair-wise point inside rectangle (bounding box) check?

Tags: matlab, geometry, vectorization

`P` is an `m*2` matrix of `m` points(`[X Y]`), and `R` is an `n*4` matrix of `n` rectangles (`[X1 Y1 X2 Y2]`). I want to form an `m*n` matrix, `C`, in a way that `C(i, j)` indicates if i-th point in `P` lies inside j-th rectangle in `R`.

**Single point single rect:**

This is the way I check if the point lies inside the rectangle:

```
c = (P(1)>=R(1))&(P(1)<=R(3))&(P(2)>=R(2))&(P(2)<=R(4));
```

for more readability:

```
c = (Px>=Rxmin)&(Px<=Rxmax))&(Py>=Rymin)&(Py<=Rymax);
```

In the code above I’m sure that `R(1)<=R(3)` and `R(2)<=R(4)`:

```
R(:, [1 3]) = sort(R(:, [1 3]), 2);
R(:, [2 4]) = sort(R(:, [2 4]), 2);
```

**Multiple points multiple rects:**

It's easy to mange `m*1` and `1*n` cases ([like second answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414156/matlab-how-to-find-a-point-in-a-bounding-box)). But I don't know how to vectorize `m*n` case. I’m currently doing it using for loops:

```
m = size(P, 1);
n = size(R, 1);
C = false(m, n);
for i=1:n
    C(:, i) = (P(:, 1)>=R(i, 1))&(P(:, 1)<=R(i, 3))& ...
        (P(:, 2)>=R(i, 2))&(P(:, 2)<=R(i, 4));
end
```

How can I vectorize it for more efficiency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you work with each column of `P` and `R` individually and then bitwise `&` them at the end:

```
Px = P(:,1);
Rx1 = R(:,1).';
Rx2 = R(:,3).';

X1 = bsxfun(@ge, Px, Rx1);
X2 = bsxfun(@le, Px, Rx2);


Py = P(:,2);
Ry1 = R(:,2).';
Ry2 = R(:,4).';

Y1 = bsxfun(@ge, Py, Ry1);
Y2 = bsxfun(@le, Py, Ry2);

C = X1 & X2 & Y1 & Y2
```

Or if you prefer:

```
C = bsxfun(@ge, P(:,1), R(:,1).')& ...  % X lower bound
    bsxfun(@le, P(:,1), R(:,3).')& ...  % X upper bound
    bsxfun(@ge, P(:,2), R(:,2).')& ...  % Y lower bound
    bsxfun(@le, P(:,2), R(:,4).');      % Y upper bound
```

---

OP has provided this timing comparison

[image]